# Spring-cloud:Could i fresh the config file when my server is not a normal configclient but zuul server?

Tags: spring-cloud

I create a config-client demo ,i can refresh its conifg file with http://localhost:11301/bus/fresh , but when i try to refresh my zuul-demo
s config-file,its error

Comment: Can you please provide more detail? versions, configuration, dependencies, etc...

Comment: thanks,i settled the question yesterday ,i forget to add the dependency of these code. <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
  </dependency>